# How to reduce the episode time in my DQN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, dqn

I have modified the [cartpole](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/classic_control/cartpole.py) environment from OpenAi so that it starts in the inverted position and has to learn the upswing. I use Google collab to run it because it's way faster than on my laptop. I thought. It´s super slow... I need 40 sec. for an episode, kinda the same time as on my laptop. I even tried to optimize it for the google TPU´s, but nothing has changed. The main time consumers are `.fit()` and `.predict()`, so I belive. I use `.predict()` here

`def get_qs(self, state): return self.model.predict(np.array(state).reshape(-1,*state.shape), workers = 8, use_multiprocessing = True)[0]`

and here also `.fit()`

```
@tf.function 
def train(self, terminal_state, step):
    "Zum trainieren lohnt es sich immer einen größeren Satz von Daten zu nehmen um ein Overfitting zu verhindern"
    if len(self.replay_memory) < MIN_REPLAY_MEMORY_SIZE:
        return
    
   # Get a minibatch of random samples from memory replay table
    minibatch = random.sample(self.replay_memory, MINIBATCH_SIZE)

    # Get current states from minibatch, then query NN model for Q values
    current_states = np.array([transition[0] for transition in minibatch])
    current_qs_list = self.model.predict(current_states)

    # Get future states from minibatch, then query NN model for Q values
    # When using target network, query it, otherwise main network should be queried
    new_current_states = np.array([transition[3] for transition in minibatch])
    future_qs_list = self.target_model.predict(new_current_states, workers = 8, use_multiprocessing = True)

    X = []
    y = []

    # Now we need to enumerate our batches
    for index, (current_states, action, reward, new_current_states, done) in enumerate(minibatch):

        # If not a terminal state, get new q from future states, otherwise set it to 0
        # almost like with Q Learning, but we use just part of equation here
        if not done:
            max_future_q = np.max(future_qs_list[index])
            new_q = reward + DISCOUNT * max_future_q
        else:
            new_q = reward

        # Update Q value for given state
        current_qs = current_qs_list[index]
        current_qs[action] = new_q

        # And append to our training data
        
        X.append(state)
        y.append(current_qs)
    
    # Fit on all samples as one batch, log only on terminal state callbacks=[self.tensorboard] if terminal_state else None
    self.model.fit(np.array(X), np.array(y), batch_size=MINIBATCH_SIZE, verbose=0, shuffle=False, workers = 8, use_multiprocessing = True)
     # Update target network counter every episode
    if terminal_state:
        self.target_update_counter += 1

    # If counter reaches set value, update target network with weights of main network
    if self.target_update_counter > UPDATE_TARGET_EVERY:
        self.target_model.set_weights(self.model.get_weights())
        self.target_update_counter = 0
```

Can anybody help me to fasten things up?

Comment: What is the version of `Tensorflow` that you are using?

Comment: I´m using TensorFlow 2.3.0 and Python 3.8.5